# UIScrollView Height getting

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiscrollview

I have cardsDetialViewController  with one scrollView in it. The height of scrollview is set to 354 and width is set to 309, in storyboard As shown in following figures.

(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19512361/iamges/cardsViewStoryboard.png)

Here is my cardsDetialViewController in storyboard
(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19512361/iamges/scrollview.png)

I created scrollview outlet and connected it to cardsDetialViewController. But in cardsDetialViewController.m,   - (void)viewDidLoad method I am calling this

```
 CGRect frame = self.cardsScrollView.frame;
```

the height of the frame is returned as 528 instead of 354 which is actual value. 
How can I get the size which I set for that scrollview in storyboard.

Comment: Can you check the autoresizingmask set to scrollView?

Comment: Hi Anupdas, thanks for reply where can I check that autoresizingmask ?.

Comment: You are not using autoLayout rite? You can see the sizeInspector (option+cmd+5) for knowing the mask.

Comment: Hey this is what I found for autoresize = W+TM+H+BM; when I printed description of scrollbar .

Comment: This how my size inspector is looking for this scrollView. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19512361/iamges/Screen%20Shot%202013-05-10%20at%201.44.08%20AM.png

Comment: You need this [mask](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35012982/Demo%20Projects/ResizingMask.png)

Comment: @Anupdas I tried that but it's the something again.